# Comparing two hashmap <String , Integer> and retrieving the key with the lowest integer value in java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am trying to compare two `hashmaps` of type `<String, Integer>` and trying to get the result based on the smallest value of integer from first map and the biggest value from second map. 
Eg:

```
hashmap1:

Key value
 A    2
 B    2
 C    4

hashmap2:
key value
 A   10
 B   20
 C    5
```

The result would be `"B  2"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative method using the stream API:

```
String key = map.entrySet().stream()
    .min((o1, o2) -> o1.getValue() - o2.getValue()).get().getKey();
```

though I admit it is quite verbose.

`key` stores the key that corresponds to the lowest value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to compare the two of them to get the largest value? If you ran something like this

```
Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> maxEntry = null;

for (Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
    {
        maxEntry = entry;
    }
}
```

You would get the largest values of either and if you must get the largest value of both then do a comparison afterwards.